# iOS developer program : Individual vs Company

Tags: iphone, account

This might seem to be a trivial question. I need to know, if I register my company under the **iOS Developer Program : Company** , worth $99 and I can now add developers under the same company.

My question is, do these developers also need to have **iOS Developer Program : Individuals** worth $99 separately?? or just a simple Apple ID will suffice??

EDIT : So in effect do I need to PAY $99(company) + $99(individual)
One more question is: How many devices can I attach with the Individual IOS Developer Program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every developer will use his Free Apple ID, and will join your team, attached to you Company subscription.
So you 'only' 99$ a year for all your Team.

You can use the account with 100 devices

Answer (score 2):

To add them to the company they will need developer accounts. However, you could just use use the company account and attach up to 100 devices to it for testing and share the certificates across all developers.

More info at:
https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enrollment.html

Comment: So that means I've to register as a **company IOS developer program** and then the developer also gets a Individual IOS Developer program. That is _$99(company) + $99(Individual)_. I've one more doubt now. How many **devices** can I connect with an Individual Apple Developer Program??

Comment: You can add upto 100 devices and you have to pay only $99